# Ionic cordova build iOS not creating build folder and getting sass gulp error

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, gulp-sass

I just upgraded my MacOS environment from Ionic CLI 1.7.14 to v5.2.6.  This also required me to upgrade NodeJS to v10.16.3.  I am having several issues but one of which is when I build the app the `platforms/ios/build` directory is not being created.

However, I can deploy the app right from Xcode to my test phone - but its all wonky, missing images, backend server api calls not working, in app url links to other in app pages not working.  Even after deploying from Xcode though there still is no build directory.  As well, Safari web inspector would open a blank window...no elements, console info, nothing.

It doesn't appear that I have any errors in my build.  Below is the --verbose output:

```
/users/macknife/dev/MyApp> ionic cordova build ios --buildFlag='-UserModernBuildSystem=0' --verbose
  ionic:lib Terminal info: { ci: false, shell: '/bin/bash', tty: true, windows: false } +0ms
  ionic:lib CLI global options: { _: [ 'cordova', 'build', 'ios' ], help: null, h: null, verbose: true, quiet: null, interactive: true, color: true, confirm: null, json: null, buildFlag: '-UserModernBuildSystem=0', project: null, '--': [] } +5ms
  ionic:lib:project Project type from config: Ionic 1 (ionic1) +0ms
  ionic:lib:project Project details: { configPath: '/Users/macknife/dev/MyApp/ionic.config.json', errors: [], context: 'app', type: 'ionic1' } +0ms
  ionic Context: { binPath: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic', libPath: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic', execPath: '/Users/macknife/dev/MyApp', version: '5.2.6' } +0ms
  ionic:lib:integrations:cordova:config Loading Cordova Config (config.xml: '/Users/macknife/dev/MyApp/config.xml', package.json: '/Users/macknife/dev/MyApp/package.json') +0ms
  ionic:lib:build build options: { '--': [],
  ionic:lib:build   engine: 'cordova',
  ionic:lib:build   platform: 'ios',
  ionic:lib:build   project: undefined,
  ionic:lib:build   verbose: false,
  ionic:lib:build   type: 'ionic1' } +0ms
  ionic:lib:telemetry Sending telemetry for command: 'ionic cordova build' [ 'ios',
  ionic:lib:telemetry   '--verbose',
  ionic:lib:telemetry   '--interactive',
  ionic:lib:telemetry   '--color',
  ionic:lib:telemetry   '--build-flag=-UserModernBuildSystem=0' ] +0ms
  ionic:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms
  ionic:lib:build Looking for ionic:build npm script. +12ms
> ionic-v1 build
  ionic:v1-toolkit:lib:gulp Using gulpfile: /Users/macknife/dev/MyApp/gulpfile.js +0ms
  ionic:v1-toolkit:lib:gulp Using gulp: /Users/macknife/dev/MyApp/node_modules/gulp/index.js +2ms
  ionic:v1-toolkit:lib:gulp Loaded gulp tasks: { default: { fn: [Function], dep: [ 'sass' ], name: 'default' }, sass: { fn: [Function], dep: [], name: 'sass' }, watch: { fn: [Function], dep: [ 'sass' ], name: 'watch' } } +957ms
[10:25:49] Invoking sass gulp task.
  ionic:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:after npm script. +3s
> cordova build ios --verbose
No scripts found for hook "before_build".
Executing script found in plugin cordova-custom-config for hook "before_prepare": plugins/cordova-custom-config/hooks/restoreBackups.js
cordova-custom-config: Loaded module dependencies
cordova-custom-config: Running restoreBackups.js
cordova-custom-config: Skipping auto-restore of config file backup(s)
Executing script found in plugin cordova-custom-config for hook "before_prepare": plugins/cordova-custom-config/hooks/applyCustomConfig.js
cordova-custom-config: Loaded module dependencies
cordova-custom-config: Running applyCustomConfig.js
cordova-custom-config: Finished applying platform config
Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
PlatformApi successfully found for platform ios
Checking for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in ios platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in ios platform. Continuing...
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for iOS at /users/macknife/dev/MyApp/platforms/ios/MyApp/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific iOS config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/ios/platform_www] to platforms/ios/www
  copy  www/css/ionic.app.css platforms/ios/www/css/ionic.app.css (updated file)
  copy  www/css/ionic.app.min.css platforms/ios/www/css/ionic.app.min.css (updated file)
  copy  www/index.html platforms/ios/www/index.html (updated file)
Current launch storyboard CDVLaunchScreen
Not changing launch storyboard setting in info plist.
Wrote out iOS Bundle Version "0.2.90" to /users/macknife/dev/MyApp/platforms/ios/MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist
No need to update build settings for launch storyboard support.
Set IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to "9.3".
Did not update build settings for launch storyboard support.
iOS Product Name has not changed (still "MyApp")
Updating icons at platforms/ios/MyApp/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/
Updating splash screens at platforms/ios/MyApp/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/
Updating launch storyboard images at platforms/ios/MyApp/Images.xcassets/LaunchStoryboard.imageset/
Updating Storyboard image set contents.json
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared iOS project successfully
Executing script found in hooks directory for hook "after_prepare": hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
Running command: /users/macknife/dev/MyApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /users/macknife/dev/MyApp
add to body class: platform-ios
Command finished with error code 0: /users/macknife/dev/MyApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /users/macknife/dev/MyApp
Executing script found in plugin cordova-custom-config for hook "after_prepare": plugins/cordova-custom-config/hooks/applyCustomConfig.js
cordova-custom-config: Loaded module dependencies
cordova-custom-config: Running applyCustomConfig.js
cordova-custom-config: Finished applying platform config
Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-facebook4 for hook "after_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4/scripts/after_prepare.js
Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-firebasex for hook "after_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-firebasex/scripts/after_prepare.js
Preparing Firebase on iOS


Ionic:

   Ionic CLI         : 5.2.6 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.0.0
   @ionic/v1-toolkit : 1.0.22

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 32 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.6.0 
   native-run  : 0.2.8 

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.11.2
   OS         : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

======================

On a hunch, I removed the auto-installed `Cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` (that seems to be standard with Ionic CLI when building a new app) and returned to using a my previous web view-plus (yes, very old, but its what I have been using until this big CLI upgrade - and it was working just fine).  I tried building again from console and it did so without any error but again no `platform/ios/build` folder - however, I could deploy my app cleanly from Xcode - all the wonky stuff was gone - and my app was working AND I could manage the app from Safari web inspector again.  Something about ionic-web view must be causing all the wonkiness - but still does not explain the build issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is often the caused by several versions of gulp installed at the same time.

Try deleting both the `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` folder. Then reinstall the dependencies with `npm i` and try building your app again.

Comment: I completely rebuilt my project and now the gulpfile.js euror has gone away.  `ionic cordova build ios` builds cleanly, but still no `/build` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar situation before. This is the solution which worked for me:

1. Remove the IOS platform `ionic cordova platform remove ios`
2. Add the platform again `ionic cordova platform add ios`
3. Use XCode to configure signature settings
4. Also in XCode under File -> Workspace settings enable the "Legacy build system"
5. Try your build again

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled my project and aligned my gulp versions and issue still was happening.

Turns out the `Preparing Firebase on iOS` was the clue.  Its the last message before the build prematurely exits, but exits with no errors, issues, warnings or anything.

`Cordova-plugin-firebasex @6.0.7` has an issue that hoses the build.  I downgraded to v6.0.6 and everything builds fine now.